make file failing with No such file or directory
I'm running makefile in Githubactions. My makefile is failing to run touch command. I'm not sure what is the error here.
Tried adding : `$(shell) to make command, still the same error. It worked in jenkins and locally.
Make file:
test:
    $(Shell prometheus/generated_config.sh --first-cluster-url "test.yl4.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com" --first-cluster-name test --first-cluster-token "test" --test-context)

Make version:
Run make --version
  make --version
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Workflow file:
- name: prometheus-deploy-${{ inputs.environment }}
        env:
          FIRST_KUBE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIRST_KUBE_TOKEN }}
          DEPLOYER_KEY: ${{ secrets.IHR_DEPLOYER_KEY }}
          FIRST_CLUSTER_URL: ${{ secrets.FIRST_CLUSTER_URL }}
          CLUSTER_NAME: ${{ secrets.CLUSTER_NAME }}
          SSH_HOST: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
        run: |
          touch DEPLOYER_KEY.pem
          echo "${DEPLOYER_KEY}" >> DEPLOYER_KEY.pem 
          chmod 0600 ./DEPLOYER_KEY.pem
          echo $SHELL
          ls prometheus/
          sudo chsh -s /bin/bash
          if [[ "true" == "true" ]]; then
             export CONFIG_ONLY_FLAG='--config-only'
             make test
             ./prometheus/generate_config.sh --first-cluster-url "${FIRST_CLUSTER_URL}" --first-cluster-name "${CLUSTER_NAME}" --first-cluster-token "${FIRST_KUBE_TOKEN}"

ERROR:
shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    FIRST_KUBE_TOKEN: ***
    IHR_DEPLOYER_KEY: ***
    FIRST_CLUSTER_URL: ***
    CLUSTER_NAME: ***
    SSH_HOST: *** 
/bin/bash
config
generate_config.sh
rules
tests
web-config.yml
prometheus/generate_config.sh --first-cluster-url "test.yl4.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com" --first-cluster-name test --first-cluster-token "test" --test-context
touch: cannot touch '/home/runner/_work/prometheus/project-prometheus/prometheus/generated_config/first_token': No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch '/home/runner/_work/prometheus/project-prometheus/prometheus/generated_config/second_token': No such file or directory


This is wrong in various ways:
test:
        $(Shell prometheus/generated_config.sh --first-cluster-url "test.yl4.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com" --first-cluster-name test --first-cluster-token "test" --test-context)

First, make is case-sensitive and the function is named $(shell ...) not $(Shell ...).  Since Shell is not a valid function, this is asking make to expand expand an undefined variable named Shell prometheus/... so your makefile does nothing.
Secondly, there's no point in using the shell function here in the first place: make always runs its recipes in the shell so using it here only makes things confusing and hard to understand.  You want just this:
test:
        prometheus/generated_config.sh --first-cluster-url "test.yl4.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com" --first-cluster-name test --first-cluster-token "test" --test-context


hmm I did try , got the same error
./prometheus/generate_config.sh --first-cluster-url "test.yl4.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com" --first-cluster-name test --first-cluster-token "test" --test-context touch: cannot touch '/home/runner/_work/amp-prometheus/amp-prometheus/prometheus/generated_config/first_bearer_token': No such file or directory touch: cannot touch '/home/runner/_work/amp-prometheus/amp-prometheus/prometheus/generated_config/second_bearer_token': No such file or directory
did not work even if I pass $(shell ...)

You docker file is weird because you first run make test which invokes the generate_config.sh command, then the docker file invokes the generate_config.sh command as well.  In any event, these touch commands are being printed by the generate_config.sh script.  We have no way of knowing what it does or why it's failing.  You will have to investigate it.  But apparently it is trying to access some directory that doesn't exist inside the docker container.
